# Why factor is not included in first differences model?

Tags: r, output, regression, plm

Let's consider data following:

```
library(plm)
data("EmplUK", package="plm")
df1<-EmplUK
df1 <- cbind(df1,"Trend" = as.numeric(as.factor(unlist(df1[, 2])))) 
> head(df1)
  firm year sector   emp    wage capital   output Trend
1    1 1977      7 5.041 13.1516  0.5894  95.7072     2
2    1 1978      7 5.600 12.3018  0.6318  97.3569     3
3    1 1979      7 5.015 12.8395  0.6771  99.6083     4
4    1 1980      7 4.715 13.8039  0.6171 100.5501     5
5    1 1981      7 4.093 14.2897  0.5076  99.5581     6
6    1 1982      7 3.166 14.8681  0.4229  98.6151     7
```

I want to perform first difference panel regression. So:

```
> plm(capital~wage+output+Trend,data=df1, model = 'fd')

Model Formula: capital ~ wage + output + Trend

Coefficients:
(Intercept)        wage      output 
  0.0111227  -0.0014415   0.0110732
```

My question is: Why 'Trend' is not included in my plm model? And is there any possibility in which I can include it?

Answer (score 1):

For calculating first differences, `plm` internally uses `c("firm", "year")` columns. This can be shown with:

```
plm(capital ~ wage + output + Trend, 
    data=df1[-which(names(df1) %in% c("firm", "year"))],
    model='fd')  ## throws a warning
# Model Formula: capital ~ wage + output + Trend
# 
# Coefficients:
#   (Intercept)        wage      output       Trend 
#      0.165677    0.076483    0.038369    0.261935
```

As we can see `"Trend"` appears now (of course the result is wrong).

You can see the reason when looking in the correlation matrix of your data.

```
round(cor(df1))
#         firm year sector emp wage capital output Trend
# firm       1    0      0   0    0       0      0     0
# year       0    1      0   0    0       0     -1     1
# sector     0    0      1   0    0       0      0     0
# emp        0    0      0   1    0       1      0     0
# wage       0    0      0   0    1       0      0     0
# capital    0    0      0   1    0       1      0     0
# output     0   -1      0   0    0       0      1    -1
# Trend      0    1      0   0    0       0     -1     1
```

`"Trend"` and `"year"` are perfectly correlated, i.e. you're experiencing [multicollinearity](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/1150/163114).

```
with(df1, cor(Trend, year))
# [1] 1
```

Using `lm` such coefficients would be displayed as `NA`, similar to

```
r <- lm(capital ~ wage + output + factor(year) + factor(firm) + Trend, 
   data=df1)$coe
r[-grep("year|firm", names(r))]
# (Intercept)        wage      output       Trend 
# -2.62878756  0.03206621  0.02363581          NA
```

whereas `plm` drops them.